# NODE.JS Error: Cannot find ffmpeg while using module Audioconcat

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

**Want to concatenate two audio files. i used an npm known as audioconcate but when i installed and configured the below code i am confronted with the following error**

```
Error: Error: Cannot find ffmpeg
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:136:22
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:123:9
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:356:16
    at nextTask (E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5057:29)
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5064:13
    at apply (E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:21:25)
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:56:12
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:840:16
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:116:11
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\utils.js:223:16
ffmpeg stderr: undefined
```

here is the code i am using: (all audio files are in the same folder also)

var audioconcat = require('audioconcat')

```
var songs = [
  'a(1).mp3',
  'a(2).mp3',
  'a(3).mp3'
]

audioconcat(songs)

  .concat('all.mp3') 
  .on('start', function (command) {
    console.log('ffmpeg process started:', command)
  })
  .on('error', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.error('Error:', err)
    console.error('ffmpeg stderr:', stderr)
  })
  .on('end', function (output) {
    console.error('Audio created in:', output)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not look like you have ffmpeg installed, it is a requirement for that package.

> **Requirements**
>
> ffmpeg with additional compilation flags --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame

https://www.npmjs.com/package/audioconcat